# how can i move failed data to another table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

COPY
EMP TABLE
DATA
TO ANOTHER TABLE
AND COPY FAILED DATA TO ANOTHER TABLE

NOTE: In emp2 table there is a check constraint `check sal > 1500` so it doesnt move the data.

I want to copy all 1500 above sal from emp to emp2 and copy the below 1500 sal to another table.

```
create or replace procedure p1 is cursor c1 is
  select * from emp;
  c number(10); 
begin
  for i in c1 loop
    insert into emp2(ename,ssno,empno) values(i.ename,i.sal,i.empno); 
end loop; 
end;
```

Comment: What's your question? Please clarify with more details. An example would be useful.

Comment: NOTE: In emp2 table there is a check constraint (check sal>1500) so it doesnt move
the data.

I want to copy all 1500 above sal from emp to emp2
and copy the below 1500 sal to another table.??


create or replace procedure p1
is
cursor c1 is select * from emp;
c number(10);
begin
for i in c1
loop
insert into emp2(ename,ssno,empno) values(i.ename,i.sal,i.empno);
end loop;
end;

Comment: Why do you want to use PL/SQL?

Comment: Actually i want it with a procedure @Alex Poole

Comment: Yes, but the question was why, when you can do it more simply in plain SQL.

Comment: in that time only i can do but i wanted it to stored in database by using plsql @WilliamRobertson

Comment: I can't post an answer until the *"Unclear what you're asking"* block is lifted, but you might look at the [`forall values of`](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/oracle-10g-adds-more-to-forall) and [multi-table `insert`](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=209) constructions.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

```
insert into ok_data (ename, ssno, empno, sal)
  select ename, ssno, empno, sal
  from emp
  where sal <= 1500;

insert into failed_data (ename, ssno, empno, sal)
  select ename, ssno, empno, sal
  from emp
  where sal > 1500;
```

---

As your comment suggests PL/SQL with a loop, then the loop should contain its own `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block, so that - once the insert into `OK_DATA` fails, exception handling section inserts data into `FAILED_DATA` table. Something like this:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select ename, ssno, empno, sal from emp) loop
    begin
      insert into ok_data (ename, ssno, empno, sal)
        values (cur_r.ename, cur_r.ssno, cur_r.empno, cur_r.sal);

    exception
      when others then
        insert into failed_data (ename, ssno, empno, sal) 
          values (cur_r.ename, cur_r.ssno, cur_r.empno, cur_r.sal);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```